# Is it possible to use java client to call c++ server in the same process using InProcessChannel?

Tags: java, c++, grpc

Both grpc-java and grpc-c++ have the support for in-process channel, which is used if grpc client and server are in the same process.

So I have a question, is it possible to use java client to call c++ server in the same process using in-process channel?

Comment: In short, no. You can't expect a pure-Java implementation to interoperate with a pure-C++ one. Though I'm guessing with some glue JNI coding it should be possible.

Comment: @rustyx can you please share the details? Can't is use Unix Domain Sockets to provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The inprocess channels in each language are language-specific. You would need to use a normal channel and a port of localhost.

While it might be possible to use `socketpair()` to do something similar, it would require some effort to get working.